# How to check if the time stored in database exceeded two hours

Tags: php

Each time a password reset req link clicked, I store the time using `now()` PHPfunction into user table in this form:

> 2015-06-15 12:02:09

How do I check date and time in format if its exceeded 2 hours? Will a simple `2*60*60` help?

Date to be taken into consideration too.. What if they clicked the link a day after and before the specified time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strtotime()` is what you're looking for if you want to do it with PHP. It would have been helpful to see code you've tried.

```
<?php
$timediff = strtotime('now') - strtotime('2015-06-15 00:02:09'); // in seconds

if( $timediff > 7200 ) { // 7200 seconds is 2 hours
    // do stuff;
}
?>
```

This will take the date into account as you've asked because the `strtotime` function returns the amount of time in seconds that has passed since epoch time (Jan 1, 1970).

Answer (score 1):

mysql has its own set of date functions

`SELECT pasword_link_stuff from table where (NOW() - INTERVAL 2 HOUR) < date_field`

Comment: what does this query do?

Comment: what you asked in the quewstion

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like,

```
select * from table where (time_to_sec(timediff('2015-06-15 12:02:09', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP )) / 3600) > 2
```

Comment: is it calculating 2 hours when fetching data?

Comment: `(time_to_sec(timediff('2015-06-15 12:02:09', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP )) / 3600)` it will just give you the difference, now it's up to you, that you want to include or exclude, this example query will fetch data where the time difference is greater than 2 hours

Comment: thanks a lot for that, but what if I want to compare after I fetched the time data from table? I mean I store and retrieve the same date time, but after I retrieve I check if it exceeded 2 hours..Is it possible>

Comment: `(time_to_sec(timediff('2015-06-15 12:02:09', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP )) / 3600)` shift this from where clause to select clause.. like

`select (time_to_sec(timediff('2015-06-15 12:02:09', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP )) tdiff from tablename`

Comment: SO the time returned in seconds and I can compare afterwards right? Thanks kamal!

Comment: Yes, You can if you wish to!